# Split db table for performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big "users" table with most of the columns (user profile) only occasionally needed, whereas a few columns (user credentials) very often. I don't like to fetch the whole row with the profile just to display the user's name.

Would splitting the table in two, ie. users and profiles be better performance wise, or worse (having to make two queries for the profile)? Is there a performance difference in MySql between fetching a row with just a few columns vs. lets say a hundred?

Thank you.

I should have mentioned that I'm on the Laravel framework. I would have to use Raw queries to SELECT the columns. I don't like the idea, but I`ll look into that.

Comment: Why don't you just fetch only required columns in your SELECT queries?

Comment: _I don't like to fetch the whole row with the profile just to display the user's name._ You don't have to. Just specify which fields to select: `SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE username='myuser'`

Comment: I think it depends on your RAM, when the whole table would not fit into RAM then an ideal indexing combined with partitioning would not make a difference, if there are many or few columns

Comment: read carefully about [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: are you asking about select * vs select <column names> ? or you worry about the column counts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old idiom in SQL development, which states that when you're actually doing `SELECT *`, you really don't want **everything** from the table.

There are a few things you could do to speed up your queries and make for better performance:

1) Select only the fields you need with your SQL statement, for example:

```
SELECT `username`, `password`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1
```

2) Add indexes to your table so that any queries which are used often can be optimised. For example, if you're looking up a user's email address on a regular basis, you might consider adding an index to the `email` column.

You might also want to look into [MySQL Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html), but I think that's not really what you need. MySQL was designed as a database to hold millions of records.

You should also bear in mind that when designing databases, it is critical that you perform at least the first three [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) of [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This ensures data integrity, and also optimizes your DB structure for your project.

Comment: Then I probably should keep the user data in one table and find a way in Laravel to fetch the needed columns dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a big "users" table

Define 'big'.

It should be trivial to define appropriate indexes on the table such that all access is of the order log(n) (where n is the number of rows) while in the absence of an index, the access is O(n). This means that the effort (and hence time taken) to retrieve a row in the absence of a suitbale in dex increases linearly with the number rows - but with an index it increases with the log of the number of rows. There are also lots of other factors to consider to get the actual time taken to retrieve a row - adding more tables increases cost, but generally the first port of call for speeding up access is to add an index (or indexes) appropriate to the queries being applied to the data. That means looking at explain plans and the table and index structure.

When the database has to read then discard data from the disk (for a full table scan or an inneficient index) then it still stores the stuff in memory - displacing data which might be useful - in some cases a full table scan can be the most efficient solution - but effectively flushes large parts of the I/O cache. In the absence of a covering index, then the whole of each row matched by the plan must be read into memory. Usually this is the expensive bit - but by using 'SELECT *' for such a table, then you are guaranteed not to have a covering index, and there are further costs in transferring and holding the data in the client.

Next, consider how often data is changing. If you've got variable length columns (varchar, CLOB etc) then an update to a row can cause the new version to be larger than the old - leading to row chaining/migration: the data for a single record can be spread further over the disk causing more seeks required to retrieve the row.

So if after checking that you've got very effective indexes, you still need to improve the performance, then splitting the columns in the table into 2 or more new tables can lead to an advantage.

Splitting rows into seperate tables on a single DB instance is unlikely to give a significant performance improvement (but it is a viable strategy where you have multiple databases, or sometimes with multiple disks).

You've not provided the structure of the table / indexes nor the explain plans for the query - hence it's impossible to make explicit suggestions for how to improve performance. Even with this information, there's no substitute for trying out the different models and measuring the performance of the system as a whole.